# Can one determine optimal parameters of a matrix to design the matrix kernel? (with specific example)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Suppose we are given a matrix $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. I would like to find $n$ real values $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ that form a diagonal matrix $A=\text{diag}(\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n)$ to *design* the kernel of the matrix $(AB-\mathbb{1})$.

Take the following as a concrete example:

Find $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that there exist $\lambda \in \text{ker}(AB-\mathbb{1})$ with $|\lambda_i| = 1 \forall i\in \{1,...,n\}$.

Is this problem well posed?

For the specific example, can one determine assumptions on $B$ that guarantee that a solution $(\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n,\lambda)$ exists?

Can one cast this a standard optimization problem such that it can be solved with for example Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me summarize your problem:

You want to design $A=\text{diag}(\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n)$ and find $\lambda$ such that $(AB-I)\lambda = 0$ and $|\lambda_i| = 1 \forall i\in \{1,...,n\}$.

It is clear that $\lambda $ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1 to the matrix $AB$ since $AB \lambda = \lambda $ which follows from $(AB-I)\lambda = 0$. Now, we want $1$ to be an eigenvector of $AB$. Let $y=B\mathbf{1}$. Let us choose $A=\text{diag}(\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n)$ such that $AB\mathbf{1}=Ay = \mathbf{1}$. The latter equality is achieved by

$$ a_i = 1/y_i$$

For the latter choice, it is of course necessary that $y_i \neq 0$.